# TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAppInstalledAndroid' of null

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Thanks in advance for your guidance in this weird issue. I have a react native component to confirm if an application is installed in Android mobile. I installed `react-native-shared-group-preferences` library which I have in node_modules.

In my component, I have the following:

```
import SharedGroupPreferences from "react-native-shared-group-preferences";

export const IsInstalled = async (packageName: string) => {
    try {
      console.log(typeof SharedGroupPreferences); //function
      await SharedGroupPreferences.isAppInstalledAndroid(
        "com.google.android.youtube"
      );
      console.log("is installed");
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return false;
    }
};
```

When I hover the mouse over isAppInstalledAndroid("com.google.android.youtube"), I am getting:

```
function SharedGroupPreferences.isAppInstalledAndroid(packageName: string): Promise<void>
```

I double checked the existance in node_modules folder:
[image]

Would you know why I am getting `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAppInstalledAndroid' of null]`?

in the Android Activity I set the content view refering to the layout:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_react_native);
    // setContentView(mReactRootView);

    mButton= findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Fragment reactNativeFragment = new ReactFragment.Builder()
                     .setComponentName("ReactNativeProject")
                     .setLaunchOptions(getLaunchOptions(appList))
                     .setFabricEnabled(false)
                     .build();
             getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.reactNativeFragment, reactNativeFragment)
                .commit();
         }
    });
```

and this is the layout:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/SettingsButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFC107"
        android:text="@string/pref_react_native"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#00356B"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I assume the issue is related to the context how the activity is created. Considering `isAppInstalledAndroid` is a ReactMethod then it is failing.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You have to use `react-native-shared-group-preferences` library or you just want to check if another application is installed?

Comment: Thanks @DinhNguyen, I am using `react-native-shared-group-preferences` library to find which applications are installed. This exact code is working when invoking React Native as an external application from Android. This issue arises when React Native is added as Fragment in Android. I guess, I have issues in context or something like that.

Comment: The issue is that packages have to be added in ReactInstanceManager. My new implementation using Fragments was missing this part. After adding the packages, the application is working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should create an answer and accept it